# É possível existir múltiplos form-login com o Spring Security na mesma aplicação?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Bem a questão de inicio pode parecer um pouco confusa, mas basicamente gostaria de saber se é possível ter mais de um formulário de validação do spring `security:form-login`, pois tenho em meu sistema dois pontos no qual a validação irá ser diferente, ou seja eu teria que ter mais de um `authentication-provider` para realizar as consultas em tabelas diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde João

É possível sim ter mais de um authentication provider, em fato, quantos quiser na mesma aplicação.

De acordo com a documentação, é possivel utilizar providers existentes no Spring Security e também criar seus customizados. Após a criação, é preciso registrar em um authentication-manager.

Ex:

```
<authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider ref="restAuthProvider/>
   <authentication-provider ref="basicAuthProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="restAuthProvider" class="br.com.auths.RestAuthProvider">
</bean>

<bean id="basicAuthProvider" class="br.com.auths.BasicAuthProvider">
</bean>
```

Ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-auth-manager